# Simple Form HABTM multiple associations on same form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I am using Simple_form/Rails 4 and want to create multiple relationships on the same form.  My models are:

```
class Characteristic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :recipes
end
```

and

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :characteristics
end
```

I have a join table

```
  create_table "characteristics_recipes", force: true do |t|
    t.integer "recipe_id"
    t.integer "characteristic_id"
  end
```

My form looks like

```
<%= simple_form_for(@recipe, html: {class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.association :characteristics, 
                      :as => :collection_select, 
                      collection: Characteristic.where(category: "Prep Time"), 
                      prompt: "Choose a Prep Time", label: "Prep Time", 
                      value_method: :id %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.association :characteristics, 
                      :as => :collection_select, 
                      collection: Characteristic.where(category: "Cook Time"), 
                      prompt: "Choose a Cook Time", label: "Cook Time", 
                      value_method: :id %>
  </div>
   <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

My params are only capturing the second association and it is as a string not an int ...

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", 
"authenticity_token"=>"GR2mvo1s7=", 
"recipe"=>{ "characteristic_ids"=>"7"}, 
"commit"=>"Create Recipe", 
"action"=>"create", 
"controller"=>"recipes"}
```

In my controller I have the following as my permitted params:

```
   def recipe_params
      params.require(:recipe).permit(:characteristic_ids)
    end
```

I have tried changing it to but this did not matter since I am not capturing the first association

```
   def recipe_params
      params.require(:recipe).permit(:characteristic_ids => [])
    end
```

How can I get multiple associations to work here?

Thank you!!!!